Unit docker.services not found
I am facing some problems working with docker.
I installed docker through the manual guide a few days ago and started doing some MySQL tasks with it. Everything worked fine and I faced no issues. So I exited from docker - and I did not do it in the manual way, if it is important - and now, after a few days, when I run the command sudo services docker start I face the error:
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
What could be the problem and how am I supposed to tackle it?
